# What are the <hbm2ddl/> configuration options for the hibernate3-maven-plugin-3.0?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, hbm2ddl, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I can't seem to find any documentation on the configuration options for hbm2ddl. Here is what I have in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Run "mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl" to generate schema -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>

    <configuration>
        <hibernatetool>
            <annotationconfiguration
                    propertyfile="src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            <hbm2ddl update="true" create="true" drop="true" export="false"
                     outputfilename="shemaDiff.ddl" format="true"
                     console="false"/>
        </hibernatetool>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I run

```
mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl
```

It builds successfully, but the database is empty when I check.

The .script file looks like the following:

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB3AAEB9E84A
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL NULLS FIRST TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 8
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
```

Interestingly, if I set console="true", it prints the correct sql table setup:

```
create table ACCOUNT (
    ACCOUNT_ID integer generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    ...
);

create table ... etc.
```

If I downgrade to version 2.2, so the plugin looks like the following:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Run "mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl" to generate schema -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

and (without changing anything else) run mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl, then the database tables are created properly from the annotated classes and the .script file reflects this:

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB3AAEB9E84A
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL NULLS FIRST TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 8
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.ACCOUNT(ACCOUNT_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ...)
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.ACCOUNT ALTER COLUMN ACCOUNT_ID RESTART WITH 1
...
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
```

Does anyone know what the configurations of hbm2ddl need to be, in order to properly create the tables with hibernate3-maven-plugin-3.0?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20060721002316/http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/confighibernate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still haven't found the documentation, but I did manage to get hbm2ddl to build the tables with hibernate3-maven-plugin-3.0.

Here's what the plugin should look like:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Run "mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl" to generate schema -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>

    <configuration>
        <hibernatetool>
            <classpath>
                <path location="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
            </classpath>

            <annotationconfiguration
                    propertyfile="src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            <hbm2ddl update="true" create="true" drop="true" export="false"
                     outputfilename="schemaDiff.ddl" format="true"
                     console="true"/>
        </hibernatetool>
    </configuration>

</plugin>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: About the documentation see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331423/352708